# Display and Use Advanced Find for Product Subscriptions by Account in Microsoft CRM 4.0

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

By default when viewing an account in edit mode you have access to Opportunities, Invoices, and Quotes which contain the products being shopped by the account and/or the sales department.

I'm trying to determine where to store, display, and use the products that an account has a subscription too.

I may not understand the implementation but it seems that there should be "Products" option directly off the root Account management window that will show the user all the products the account has purchased.

We are trying to integrate this with our production tracking system where product sales can originate from other channels that will not flow through CRM first. This product subscription does not fit into the Opportunity, Quote, or Invoice model because they are confirmed recurring sales that were automatically purchased via tools like a Public Website, Portal, etc.

By enabling this tracking in CRM we can use the advanced find feature to facilitate follow up sales and marketing efforts.

Example: Find everyone who is subscribed to model A, so we can notify them of a new holiday campaign where they can get 10% off on all add-ons.

It's my assumption that this is a common scenario, however I'd like to better understand how to approach this within the world of Microsoft CRM.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to CRM, it is possible to create custom entities with exactly the relationships described in your question.

So within CRM you could create a new Entity called Product and define a many to one relationship with Account.  During this process you will be able to define the relationship behavior such as cascading rules.

It is not recommended to interact directly with the CRM database, however you have access to Platform Related Services via a web service, by invoking methods on this service it would be possible to create entries from your public website.

Answer (score 0):

Asssuming this is a report and no interactivity is required:

Create a report that can show the records in desired form with SSRS

Publish in CRM and show in an IFRAME with proper parameters that filter the records for the open Account.

Thats All!